# katalon studio setText not working in ie browser

Tags: katalon-studio

I have used WebUI.setText to set firstname and used WebUI.getAttribute to get the value. WebUI.setText is not working in ie, but works in all browsers. 
Here is my code

```
def firstname= WebUI.setText(findTestObject('Object Repository/Firstname/Page_MTW Expansion Cohort 2 Rent Re/input_firstName'), 'hello')
WebUI.delay(3)
firstname= WebUI.getAttribute(findTestObject('Object Repository/Firstname/Page_MTW Expansion Cohort 2 Rent Re/input_firstName'), 'value')
println(firstname)
WebUI.delay(3)
if (firstname == '') {
     throw new com.kms.katalon.core.exception.StepErrorException('firstname is Empty')
     }else if(!firstname.matches('^[a-zA-Z]+$')){
      println(firstname)
      throw new com.kms.katalon.core.exception.StepErrorException('firstname should have alphabets')

     }else{
     System.out.println("firstname")
     }
```

Even after give the firstname in setText its giving 'firstname is Empty is empty error. 
Has anyone came across this issue.